Android: FirebaseAnalytics.logEvent() doesn't work for any event other than "screen_view"
We have two different apps in our company. We use the same base code for both apps, 95% of the app is using the shared code. The only difference is in styles, fonts, strings and applicationId.
Both apps are fully connected to their firebase accounts as we use other features as well.
However, analytics works perfectly well in one of our apps, while in the other one, we can only see "screen_view" event in our firebase console.
I have done all these:
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(applicationContext)
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(applicationContext).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)

<meta-data
  android:name="google_analytics_default_allow_ad_personalization_signals"
  android:value="false" />

app/
├── src/
│   ├── app1_dev/
│   │   └── google-services.json
│   ├── app1_prod/
│   │   └── google-services.json
│   ├── app2_dev/
│   │   └── google-services.json
│   ├── app2_prod/
│   │   └── google-services.json


The problem is even for our second app, everything regarding firebase works fine, except that you cannot log any events apart from "screen_view".
And I checked the "screen_view" events are not automatic. They contain all the properties that I attached to them, and they will get registered 10 times if I call the logEvent 10 times.
